# Meaning of "rotated about the y axis to form a solid" here?

Tags: geometry

I am unsure of what the scenario is that the problem is describing below. I am not sure how the region between these two curves is constructed, or what the solid would look like- is it that it is rotated 360 degrees in all directions such that it traces the outline of the sphere? I would appreciate explanation as to these matters.
thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pictured below is a cross-section view of the described solid of revolution.  A representative horizontal slice of the solid is shown in red.

[image]

An animation with varying horizontal slices is shown below:

[image]

The solid without any slicing but with partial opacity:

[image]

The question is asking you for the largest possible area for the red ring.  What is the area and at what height of the cross-section is it attained?